# Print internals of a predicate function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Can anyone help me understand how can i print the internal of this predicate function ***in kotlin***?
I want to ***print value of abc & def*** in xyz function as you see in code. In actual code i want to use this value in error message.
[image: Debug]

Reference code:

[image: Code]

Comment: Why does your error message need the internals of a lambda? This is very much a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Example this xyz function is reusable function. In this case, whenever the condition/predicate in it is not met, I want to print what was the condition that was not met. I want to avoid passing a string saying print this when condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Well that's not possible then. You cannot print arbitrary conditions like that. Even if you were able to print the value of `$abc` and `$def`, it still won't help much. You wouldn't be able to get the constants and operators used in the condition. Have a look at how unit testing frameworks do this. e.g. [kotest.io](https://kotest.io).

Comment: If you want to get the source code as a string, there's no easy way to do this. The closest is probable to create an exception, and examine the stack trace (but don't throw the exception). The stack trace will show the file and line number pl.kotl.in/Goe0S6BzV. Alternatively you could dynamically evaluate an expression with a scripting engine stackoverflow.com/a/44009876/4161471. But I doubt these ideas are a good solution, because I with @Sweeper, this looks like an XY problem. Why not require a string description for each validation?

Comment: Why not have the validation return a _list_ of failures (either as strings, or as some more structured object)? If if returns an empty list, then you know it passed validation — and if not, then you have information on _why_ it failed, information that could be useful for unit tests, for logging, or even for returning from your API or showing to users (after suitable processing).